# Automatically Organize data in a sheet differently (in order to create a dynamically updated graph)

Tags: excel, date, time, graph, vba

I currently have this in sheet1 columns A,B,C:

Date    Time    Worker
 
04/04/2016  4,5 John
 
05/04/2016  2   John
 
06/04/2016  6,5 John
 
07/04/2016  0   --
 
08/04/2016  0,5 Charles
 
08/04/2016  2   John
 
08/04/2016  0,5 William
 
09/04/2016  0   --
 
10/04/2016  0   --
 
11/04/2016  9   John
 
11/04/2016  3,75    William

I want this in sheet2 columns A,B,C,D (or more in case of more names):

Date    Charles John    William
04/04/2016  0   4,5 0
05/04/2016  0   2   0
06/04/2016  0   6,5 0
07/04/2016  0   0   0
08/04/2016  0,5 2   0,5
09/04/2016  0   0   0
10/04/2016  0   0   0
11/04/2016  0   9   3,75

I need this because I need to make a graph and data has to be organised like this or I'm not able to create the graph! 
The code (which i believe it's the only way) has to work with any given dates, times or worker names! Worker names in alphabetical order if you can.
I don't have any clue how to code this and it is giving me nightmares for weeks. Really need all the help for this one.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant, but the dates i get always appear in chronological order. Might make the code easier...

Comment: I've added the excel and excel-vba tags to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a guess since you didn't say what the chart should display.

I am pretty sure you can create this chart without the second sheet and a macro.

Try this:

1. Format the Range containing the data as table ( Select Range, Home -> Styles -> Format as Table) When you add a new row this table will automatically extend.
2. Create a Pivot-Chart ( Select all cells in the new table, Insert -> PivotTable (the Name, not the symbol) -> PivotChart)
3. Choose a destination for the PivotChart
4. Click in the Pivot-Field and select your 3 entries

It should look like this (I filtered the "--" Workers):

[image]

Play around in the 4 fields (drag&drop) to fit it your style. If you add new rows simply right click anywhere in the pivot table and press refresh.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I did this in Excel 2010.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.